# Is AppTrackingTransparency permission needed when only collecting data for user registration?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am bit confused about AppTrackingTransparency permission requirements.
My app does not sell or transfer data to any third party company.
My app has Registration Page, where user will provide his address,city,state and cell Number as part of registration.

For search i need GPS location for which I already prompt user for permission.

So was wonder if i need to implement AppTrackingTransparency ?